# How do I end javascript program mid program

Tags: javascript

I need some help ending my program. Is there a command to end it halfway through? In this short guess the number game i made everything goes fine unless the first person wins because it has to complete the loop even after the game has ended

```
 var rdmNumber = Math.random();
 var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 100;
 var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
 var playerOne = prompt("Player 1 please enter your name...");
 var playerTwo = prompt("Player 2 please enter your name...");
 while (userInput != theNumber) {
     var userInput = prompt(playerOne + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
     if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerOne + "      has won!");
     } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
     } else {
         alert("Lower");
     }
     var userInput = prompt(playerTwo + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
     if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerTwo + "  has won!");
     } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
     } else {
         alert("Lower");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use break; to break the while loop like this:

```
 var rdmNumber = Math.random();
 var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 100;
 var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
 var playerOne = prompt("Player 1 please enter your name...");
 var playerTwo = prompt("Player 2 please enter your name...");
 while (userInput != theNumber) {
     var userInput = prompt(playerOne + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
     if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerOne + "      has won!");
         break; // it will break the while loop
     } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
     } else {
         alert("Lower");
     }
     var userInput = prompt(playerTwo + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
     if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerTwo + "  has won!");
         break; // it will break the while loop
     } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
     } else {
         alert("Lower");
     }
 }
```

Or you can define the process as a function when someone win the game return a value and it will end :

```
function game() {
    var rdmNumber = Math.random();
    var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 100;
    var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
    var playerOne = prompt("Player 1 please enter your name...");
    var playerTwo = prompt("Player 2 please enter your name...");
    while (userInput != theNumber) {
      var userInput = prompt(playerOne + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
      if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerOne + "      has won!");
         return ; // it will end the function
      } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
      } else {
         alert("Lower");
      }
      var userInput = prompt(playerTwo + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
      if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerTwo + "  has won!");
         return ; // it will end the function
      } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
      } else {
         alert("Lower");
      }
    }
}

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `continue`

```
while (userInput != theNumber) {
     var userInput = prompt(playerOne + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
     if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerOne + "      has won!");
         continue;
     } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
     } else {
         alert("Lower");
     }
     var userInput = prompt(playerTwo + ", Take a Guess (0-100)");
     if (userInput == theNumber) {
         alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct. " + playerTwo + "  has won!");
     } else if (userInput < theNumber) {
         alert("Higher");
     } else {
         alert("Lower");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The break statement, which was briefly introduced with the switch
>   statement, is used to exit a loop early, breaking out of the enclosing
>   curly braces.
>
> To handle all such situations, **JavaScript provides break and continue
>   statements**. These statements are used to immediately come out of any
>   loop or to start the next iteration of any loop respectively.

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var x = 1;
document.write("Entering the loop<br /> ");
while (x < 20)
{
  if (x == 5){ 
     break;  // breaks out of loop completely
  }
  x = x + 1;
  document.write( x + "<br />");
}
document.write("Exiting the loop!<br /> ");
//-->
</script>
```

Information courtesy of [TutorialsPoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm)

Answer (score 0):

By changing a bit your logic:

Store Player names into an Array, change turn using 0,1,0,1... numbers,
Use only one prompt!! The current player is defined by players[turnNumber]

```js
var rnd = Math.round( Math.random() * 5), // 0 - 5
    res = -1, // Result
    pl = [],  // ["Ethan", "Roko"]
    t = 0;    // turn: 0,1,0,1... (0 = 1st player)

for(var i=0; i<2; i++) pl[i] = prompt("Player"+ (i+1) +", please enter your name:");

while (res !== rnd) {
    res = parseInt( prompt( pl[t] + ", take a Guess (0-5)"), 10);  
    alert( res===rnd ? (res +" is correct! "+ pl[t] +" has won!") : (res<rnd? "Higher" : "Lower"));
    t = ++t % 2; // increment turn and reset to 0 if === 2 Results in: 1,0,1,0...
}
```